# AWS failed to create backend for amplify app

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-amplify

I am following [this tutorial](https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/hands-on/build-react-app-amplify-graphql/module-two/) for creating a React app in AWS.

In step `Initialize the Amplify app` of section 3, I see the following error (i.e. `Setting up Admin UI failed.`) in the `Backend environments` tab:

[image: Setting up Admin UI failed.]

I know that I have a limited account from our administration side, but I don't know what role is missing that I cannot create the backend for my app!

Does anyone have any idea that, how I can find out what role is missing that I am not allowed to create the `Amplify Backend`?

Also in the console tab no info is printed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem when I tried to deploy from the Admin UI sandbox app, as a ROOT user on my AWS account. I fixed it after I went to Billing and completed the payment info requirements.

Before that I couldn't even access DynamoDB tables (which are used by AWS Amplify and Admin UI).

If this doesn't work, you can try having Amplify and maybe DynamoDB related roles enabled in IAM for your user.

You can start with these roles:

1. AdministratorAccess-Amplify
2. AmazonDynamoDBFullAccess